# English commentary of Sahih Bukhari and Muslim?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Is there any English/translated commentary of Sahih Bukhari and Sahih Muslim, preferably free/purchasable online? I tried to do a Google search but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is an English translation available of the commentary on Sahih Muslim by Imam Nawawi, translated by someone named Adil Salahi. It is not finished yet. You can get the part which is done. It is available online via Amazon etc. You can also find some volumes of it on [z-library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Library) and similar places. Credits to [Medi1Saif](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/13438/medi1saif) for telling me about it.

[image]